# Tar files in one location

Tags: unix

At 10 A.M files are like below say in one of the location

A.log,B.log

Tar file should contain A.log and B.log.   Tar file name should be like 
archival_file__oror_datetimestamp.tar

At 11 A.M if files are like below

A.log,B.log,C.log

Now the tar file which is getting created now should not contain A.log and B.log it should contain C.log only

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly guess the intention of your question you might want to do something like

```
# 10AM:
tar -cf /path/to/tarfile/archival_file__oror_10AM.tar /path/to/logfiles/*.log

# 11 AM
tar -N /path/to/tarfile/archival_file__oror_10AM.tar -cf /path/to/tarfile/archival_file__oror_11AM.tar /path/to/logfiles/*.log
```

The second command will only put files newer than `archival_file__oror_10AM.tar` into the new archive.

Comment: how do i compare two exported parameters from my shell script

Comment: @user676421: To be honest, I don't understand the correlation of your comment to your question resp. to my answer...

Comment: In my script i need to Write a script that archives the files created by particular userid from error,log,reject folders and copy them to your $HOME directory for every 1 hour( use can use crontab command here).
Also the  backup should be incremental.
Ex:At 10 A.M files are like below say in one of the location
A.log,B.log
Tar file should contain A.log and B.log.   Tar file name should be like archival_file_<project>_<error>or<reject>or<log>_datetimestamp.tar
At 11 A.M if files are like below
a.log,B.log,C.log
now tar            should not contain A.log and B.log it should contain C.log only

Comment: And what *exported parameters* do you mean?